# Stock management using PHP and Mysql

Tags: mysql, database-design

I have a PHP application to manage Stock of small company. I have a problem of adding new quantity in stock because that item quantity price has changed. Here are some column of my tables

```
Id     ITEM      Quantity  price  date type .....
1       STK1         5      50EUR  2016   Spare parts
```

so I want to add new quantity with same reference but new price like this

```
  STK1         2     70EUR  2016   Spare parts
```

How Can I manage this case?

Answer (score 0):

If Item column is a unique key, drop that constraint and add a new unique key(item, price),
then you will be able to have rows of the same item with different prices.

Comment: Nakitibalda please explain more thats What I need exactly

Answer (score 0):

Create a table for item types. Each record in that table would represent an item type and would have an Id, item, type. Create a table for quantities, which will have an Id, a foreign key for the item type table, a Quantity, a price and a date.

Answer (score 0):

Key of solving this case in the accounting policy for stock: fifo, lifo, by middle price,exact party. This is will define data model for solution. Any case you wiil be have the table like (timestamp/date,sku_id, quantity,total) for calculation price of SKU in stock and some OLAP for this transactions